# HTTP Interceptor in Angular 4.2.5

Tags: javascript, angular

## Interceptor

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

## Errors

```
ERROR in C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/src/app/app.module.ts (5,9): Module '"C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/node_modules/@angular/http/http"' has no exported member 'HTTP_INTERCEPTORS'.

ERROR in C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/src/app/interceptors/401.interceptor.ts (2,9): Module '"C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/node_modules/@angular/http/http"' has no exported member 'HttpEvent'.

ERROR in C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/src/app/interceptors/401.interceptor.ts (2,20): Module '"C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/node_modules/@angular/http/http"' has no exported member 'HttpInterceptor'.

ERROR in C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/src/app/interceptors/401.interceptor.ts (2,37): Module '"C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/node_modules/@angular/http/http"' has no exported member 'HttpHandler'.

ERROR in C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/src/app/interceptors/401.interceptor.ts (2,50): Module '"C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/node_modules/@angular/http/http"' has no exported member 'HttpRequest'.

ERROR in C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/src/app/interceptors/401.interceptor.ts (6,56): Cannot find name 'Observable'.

ERROR in C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/src/app/app.module.ts (5,9): Module '"C:/Users/mypc/workspace/angularapp/node_modules/@angular/http/http"' has no exported member 'HTTP_INTERCEPTORS'.
```

Comment: Hence the question See the title

Answer (score 1):

The correct package is `@angular/common/http`. And, by the way, I think that it's only available as of 4.3.x versions. `@angular/http` will be deprecated in the future.

Comment: And that's why I have mentioned I am looking for a solution for angular 4.2.5

Answer (score -1):

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";
import {LoaderService} from '../loader/loader.service';
import {LocalStorageService} from '../_services/localstorage.service';

@Injectable()
export class InterceptedHttp extends Http {
    router: Router;
    loaderService:LoaderService;
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions,private _router: Router,
        private _loaderService:LoaderService,private _localStorageService:LocalStorageService) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
        this.router = _router;
        this.loaderService=_loaderService;
    }    
    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        url = this.updateUrl(url);
        return this.intercept(super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        url = this.updateUrl(url);
        let data=body;//url.endsWith('token')?body:JSON.stringify(body);//fr token url only
        return this.intercept(super.post(url, data, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        url = this.updateUrl(url);
        return this.intercept(super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        url = this.updateUrl(url);
        return this.intercept(super.delete(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    private updateUrl(req: string) {
        this.showLoader();
        return environment.origin +'/'+ req;
    }

    private getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (options == null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }
        if (options.headers == null) {
            options.headers = new Headers();
        }
        options.withCredentials=true;
        options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        options.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this._localStorageService.getAuthToken());
        //options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return options;
    }


    private onEnd(): void {
        this.hideLoader();
    }
    private showLoader(): void {
        this.loaderService.show();
    }
    private hideLoader(): void {
        this.loaderService.hide();
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        //return observable.map(response => response.json())
        return observable.catch((err, source) => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                alert('You are not authorized to access the resource');
                //setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate(['/login']), 3000);
                setTimeout(() => document.location.href='/login', 3000);                
                return Observable.empty();
            }
            else if (err.status === 404) {
                console.log(['http service',err]);
                 document.location.href='/not-found';                
                return Observable.empty();
            }
             else {
                console.log(['htto errir',err]);
                err.errors=this.parseErrors(err);
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        }).finally(() => {
            this.onEnd();
        });
    }

    parseErrors(response): Array<string>
    {
        let errors:Array<string>=new Array<string>();

        if (response) {
            response=JSON.parse(response._body);
            if (response.error_description) {
                errors.push(response.error_description);
            }
            if (response.message) {
                errors.push(response.message);
            }
            for (var key in response.modelState) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.modelState[key].length; i++) {
                    errors.push(response.modelState[key][i]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            errors.push('Server response null');
        }
        return errors;
    }
}
```

You can create HttpInterceptor in Angular4 like this and HttpFactory like below:

```
import {XHRBackend, Http, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {InterceptedHttp} from "./http.interceptor";
import {LoaderService} from '../loader/loader.service';
import {LocalStorageService} from '../_services/localstorage.service';

export function httpFactory(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions,router:Router,
    loaderService:LoaderService,localStorageService:LocalStorageService): Http {
    return new InterceptedHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions,router,loaderService,localStorageService);
}
```

I am using the localstorage in this if you don't require remove accordingly

```
{
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: httpFactory,
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions,Router,LoaderService,LocalStorageService ]
},
```

Call like this in the `app.module.ts` inside the providers.

Comment: InterceptedHttp  class contains all the CRUD operation functions which can handle automatic displaying of loader, use of authToken in case we  need to pass authtoken in header for webapi, updating url with the action name and base url from `environment.ts`

in your component you can import simply http.
`import { Http } from '@angular/http';`
and use like common http call.